# AMD/Ati VGA driver makes Ubuntu stop on Boot

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

Yesterday I bought a Dell Inspiron N5010 which comes with following specs:

- i5-640m
- 6 GB RAM
- Ati/Amd mobility radeon HD 5470

Because Ubuntu 16.04 **doesn't have fglrx** driver I installed 14.04 and machine is working fine.

The problem is the default driver for VGA is "**Xserver Ati Driver**" and I want to change it to "**fglrx**". Whenever I switched to Fglrx driver, computer **won't boot up, stuck at black screen and doesn't let me go to Grub with left shift key or open tty with ctrl+alt+F1/F2** etc.

So far I tried:

1. Enable fgrlx driver from additional sources and restart.
2. Because it becomes that problem purged it(ubuntu made xserver
   default after that)
3. Downloaded fgrlx driver from AMD support site and installed
4. 2.step repeated so I purged again.

Currently I have xserver driver and it has problems with current **Chrome/Chromium** on 14.04 so I want to enable and use **fglrx** driver again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I found the answer before people suggested.

After installing manual driver you need to write:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
```

After writing this command reboot. My problem is solved by applying this step between manuel driver install and reboot process.